# Partially Flatten Nested Collections in Java using Lambdas

Tags: java, lambda, collections

I have a nested collection as such

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, List<Integer>>> nodes = new TreeMap<>()
```

I need to convert the inner map into a `List<List<Integer>>`. The order of the inner list has to be preserved. Essentially for each entry in the outer map, iterate through the inner map, add the List as is to the List of Lists.

I can do it the old fashioned way.

```
    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, TreeMap<Integer, List<Integer>>> entry : nodes.entrySet()) {
        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> outer = entry.getValue();
        ArrayList<Integer> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> inner : outer.entrySet()) {
            tmp.addAll(inner.getValue());
        }
        result.add(tmp);
    }
```

How do to this with lambdas? This doesn't work

```
nodes.entrySet().stream().flatMap(e -> e.getValue().entrySet().stream()).map(e2 -> result.add(e2.getValue()))
```

Comment: Why do you think, `map` was the right operation for performing `result.add(…)`?

Comment: The idea was to perform some function on each element in the stream, an add in this case.

Comment: A function evaluates an input to a result; that especially applies to `Function` used in `map`. Adding to `result` is an action that produces no result, in other word, consumes the element. So `forEach(Consumer)` should come as a natural choice.

Comment: Yep, I understand now. It's just due to my unfamiliarity with the Java 8 features.

Answer (score 2):

> How do to this with lambdas? This doesn't work

Here you never invoke a termination operation, so the stream is never consumed. :

```
nodes.entrySet().stream().flatMap(e -> e.getValue().entrySet().stream()).map(e2 -> result.add(e2.getValue()))
```

Add any terminal operation such as `count()` and you could see the stream operated.
Don't forget that Streams are lazy and so the computation is effectively performed only when the terminal operation is invoked.

So you guess that your way is not the right way to do things with Stream.
You don't need to use the `List` as a variable that you will populate in the stream.  Streams are designed to collect as they produce a result and the collect to a `List` is finally the terminal operation that missed in your initial code.

Besides as a side note you should just stream the values of each Map level instead of the entries since you never use the keys.
Here the code with for each step the actual return type :

```
List<List<Integer>> result =
        nodes.values() // Collection<Map<Integer, List<Integer>>>
             .stream() // Stream<Map<Integer, List<Integer>>> 
             .flatMap(m -> m.values() // Collection<List<Integer>>> 
                           .stream()) // Stream<List<Integer>>> 
             // flatMap() prevents Stream<Stream<...>>. 
             // Indeed we get just Stream<List...>>
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Adding “any terminal operation” does not necessarily have the desired effect. Especially `count()`, which can skip a preceding `map` step, as it doesn’t affect the resulting count.

Answer (score 1):

This one should do the trick:

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, List<Integer>>> nodes = new TreeMap<>();
List<List<Integer>> list = nodes.values()
    .stream()
    .flatMap( map -> map.values().stream() )
    .collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

Explanation:
First you get stream of maps from map by using:

```
nodes.values().stream()
```

then you flatten those maps with:

```
.flatMap( map -> map.values().stream() )
```

And finally collect them with:

```
.collect( Collectors.toList() )
```